# Add Observer for end of short, high resolution video

Tags: swift, swift3, avplayer, notificationcenter

I am trying to play a 4k Video in the AVPlayer with Swift 3 for iOS12 and it works totally fine, but i want this video to play inside a loop. I found articles that stated, that you should use this method to register for the end of the video playback:

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.replay), 
    name:NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
```

In this case `self.replay` is beeing called once the player reached the end of the video. This works fine for normal videos, but once i try to play a ~4 second long video it does not loop.
The replay function looks like this:

```
@objc func replay() {
    self.playerViewController!.player?.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
    self.playerViewController!.player!.playImmediately(atRate: 1)
}
```

Im adding the Observer in the presenting ViewController's `viewDidLoad`.
Is this a race-condition, because as stated longer videos work fine? How can i prevent this behaviour.

*(Sidenote: Not a regular poster, so please tell me if my question is asked wrong or hard to understand)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(replay), 
name:NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)

@objc func replay() {
    self.playerViewController!.player!.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
    self.playerViewController!.player!.play()
}
```

Not sure what `playImmediately(atRate:)` does, however, I know in my experience playing videos on loop is to reset the player to time zero, as you have done. Then, just naturally play the video.

**ADDITION:** On another note, you can WAIT until the video is ready to play to add the observer AND start the video.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: [], context: nil)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if(keyPath == "status" && self.playerViewController!.player!.status == .readyToPlay) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(replay), name:NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
        self.playerViewController!.player!.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: `play()` sets the rate of the playback to 1. `playImmediately(atRate: 1)` does this too.

Comment: Added on to that.

Comment: looks promising, will try it!

Comment: Added even more haha. Missed the `if(keyPath == "status")` portion first time around

Comment: Okay i just found something that did the trick! Inserted a small `usleep` right before playing inside the Observer. This is totally fine for me. Thank you so much for helping! Accepting your answer even though its not the most beautiful solution with a usleep in it

Comment: Let me know if I can do anything else!